# Apache Airflow 1.9 install on debian 8 from GitHub

Tags: airflow

I installed Apache airflow 1.9 from GitHub thanks to this command line on debian 9: `pip install git+https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow.git@v1-9-stable`

However, I have an error during the `airflow initdb` caused by Fernet, do you know how to solve this issue?

```
   INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 947454bf1dff -> d2ae31099d61, Increase text size for MySQL (not relevant for other DBs' text types)
    [2017-12-27 17:19:24,586] {models.py:643} ERROR - Failed to load fernet while encrypting value, using non-encrypted value.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 639, in set_extra
        fernet = get_fernet()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 103, in get_fernet
        raise AirflowException('Failed to import Fernet, it may not be installed')
    AirflowException: Failed to import Fernet, it may not be installed
    [2017-12-27 17:19:24,601] {models.py:643} ERROR - Failed to load fernet
```

And how can I specify extrapackage like in `pip install apache-airflow[gcp-api]` from my previous pip command install with GitHub?

How to install the latest 1.9.0RC too? I have an assertionError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During install from source you have to replace fernet_key in airflow.cfg such as you can find in the docs [here](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/configuration.html#connections).

Answer (score 8):

The answer marked as good have a broken link, if you have landed here as me and it continues broken, these steps have worked for me:

- `pip install cryptography`
- `python -c "from cryptography.fernet import Fernet; print(Fernet.generate_key().decode())"`
- Add the generated key to the config file `airflow.cfg`, `fernet_key = YOUR_GENERATED_KEY`

Answer (score 0):

In apache-airflow documentation, the script for generating fernet key is apparently wrong.
it says to use the following script.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
fernet_key= Fernet.generate_key()
print(fernet_key) # your fernet_key, keep it in secured place!
```

but it raises an exception at 'airflow initdb' command.
to solve this instead of `Fernet.generate_key()` use `Fernet.generate_key().decode()` as shown in @skozz answer.